# WebRTC and Django

Tags: django, webrtc

I want to be able to use a data channel for the client connecting to my django site in order to send data to the django server and have it process that data (as opposed to using ajax for instance). I tried searching the web for the but could't find anything usefull. Is it possible to do what i'm asking?

Comment: This question does not make much sense. WebRTC is a browser to browser connection. WebRTC cannot be used for browser to server connections.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize this is a fairly old question, but there's misinformation in the reply above. WebRTC is a *peer to peer* protocol, not specifically a *browser to browser* protocol. In other words, the fact that a browser is a WebRTC peer is an implementation detail, not a standards requirement.

The [IETF requirements document, section 3.4.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-use-cases-and-requirements-12#section-3.4.3) specifically gives an example of a server-based peer for a video conferencing use case. Having said that, it's a nontrivial project; look at Asterisk's rtcweb support or [Erizo](http://lynckia.com/licode/index.html) for examples in the wild.